# Group data from reference table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have reference table `user_client` in MySQL 5.6 which looks like:

```
user_id | client_id
-------------------
    1   |    1
    1   |    2
    1   |    3
    2   |    1
    2   |    3
```

How could I query this table to get result grouped by `user_id`, like:

```
user_id | clients
-------------------
    1   |  1,2,3
    2   |  1,3
```

Thank you!

Comment: Read  up GROUP_CONCAT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `group_concat()`

```
select user_id, group_concat(client_id)
from tablename
group by user_id
```

Comment: It's exactly what I need, thank you! Marked as solution, would appreciate if you voted the question

Comment: if you want client_id in ascending order, you can append "ORDER BY client_id" inside group_concat.